# AWS DMS Task failed with error: Error executing source loop; Stream component failed at subtask

Tags: amazon-web-services, database-replication, aws-dms

I want to migrate my PostgresDB hosted in cloud service to S3. I am using AWS DMS service. it ran fine for a few days now I'm getting below error
load type: Full load, ongoing replication

Error:

```
 Replication task has failed. Reason: Last Error An internal WAL  
 conversational protocol error has occurred. Task error notification  
 received from subtask 0, thread 0 [reptask/replicationtask.c:2880]  
 [1020452] Error executing source loop; Stream component failed at subtask  
 0, component st_0_GDGOUN5DP3SJ76DYE7TDBHIOEMTNOLX76VDNIQQ; Stream  
 component 'st_0_GDGOUN5DP3SJ76DYE7TDBHIOEMTNOLX76VDNIQQ' terminated  
 [reptask/replicationtask.c:2888] [1020452] Stop Reason RECOVERABLE_ERROR  
 Error Level RECOVERABLE
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.